# pre_filter() in Kohana 2.x not working as expected

Tags: php, kohana-2

As of Kohana 2.x documentation,`pre_filter()` will execute before validation of input fields but its not working as of expected.

I'm trying to `trim` input values entered by user before validation as,

```
$post = Validation::factory($_POST);
$post->pre_filter('trim');
```

If try to view the input value entered by user as,

```
echo 'a'.$post->name.'b'; // to observe white spaces appended alphabets
```

echo's `a  john b`,actually it should be `ajohnb` means still white spaces exists. What might the wrong in this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should do:

```
$post = Validation::factory($_POST);
$post->pre_filter('trim');
$post->validate();
```

Only when you call validate() pre filters are applied.

http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/validation